Cannot login to console when VNC is running in Ubuntu 24.04 (RT, raspi)
uname -a:
Linux p4-1u-rt 6.8.0-2015-raspi-realtime #16-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_RT Mon Dec  2 13:40:09 UTC 2024 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
$ loginctl
SESSION  UID USER  SEAT  TTY   STATE  IDLE SINCE
4 1002 moose -     -     active no   -
c1 1002 moose -     pts/1 active no   -
c2  120 gdm   seat0 tty1  active yes  6min ago
$ ps -efw | grep vnc
root        1403       1  0 19:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/tigervncsession moose :2
moose       1424    1403  0 19:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/tigervncserver -fg :2
moose       1477    1424  7 19:10 ?        00:01:47 /usr/bin/Xtigervnc :2 -localhost=1 -desktop p4-1u-rt:2 (moose) -rfbport 5902 -PasswordFile /tmp/tigervnc.IURHMJ/passwd -SecurityTypes VncAuth -auth /home/moose/.Xauthority -geometry 1920x1200 -depth 24
I tried enabling RDP login and/or share, but I find that while I can connect an RDP session, I cannot change the display size (640x4xx). So, I installed tigervncserver and enabled the :2 service for my login id. With no remote session started, I try to login at the console. I get a splash window that says I cannot login because a remote session is running. The window offers a cancel option and a force quit option. Force quit does nothing. I have to open a remote session and log out before I can login on the console.
How can I configure the system so that no remote session exists until I establish one via VNC? I have not had this problem on other versions of Ubuntu.,
